# Is it possible to loop through the repetitions of a gallery's members?

Tags: loops, gallery, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I have a gallery that repeats its contents. It has one text input for a person's name and another for their email. Users may click a plus icon (the icon is not in the gallery) to produce a new row that has both of these text inputs. They can click the plus icon as many times as they like, and it will produce a new row each time. I believe the technical term for such a set up is "repeating table".

My hope was that I could use `ForAll(galleryName.AllItems, [...])` to loop through each of these text inputs and write each pair as a new row in my back end SharePoint List. However, it appears that `.AllItems` loops through the members that make up the gallery rather than the elements that the user sees. For example, I believe that a repeating table with 100 repetitions of its row would have the same number of items in `galleryName.AllItems` as a repeating table that only had its original row.

Is there any way to write a loop that loops through the members of a gallery and respects the repetitions? My ultimate goal would be to write some code like this

```
ForAll(galleryName.AllItems As gal, //Doesn't work because AllItems isn't what I want.
    Patch('My SharePoint List',
           Defaults('My SharePoint List'),
           {Name: gal.txtInputThatHoldsTheName.Text, Email: gal.txtInputThatHoldsTheEmail.Text}))
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to have a hidden label (or any other control) that stores the current state of each row, e.g. an existing row would have the label with the text "existing"/empty and any new rows added by clicking the + sign would be "New".

Then in your ForAll, you'd filter the gallery where the `YourLabel.Text = "New"`

```
ForAll(
    Filter(galleryName.AllItems, YourLabel.Text = "New"),
    Patch('My SharePoint List',
    Defaults('My SharePoint List'),
    { 
        Name: txtInputThatHoldsTheName.Name, 
        Email: txtInputThatHoldsTheEmail.Email 
    }
    )
)
```

You don't even need to use `gal.txtInputThatHoldsTheName` for it to work, simply use the `ControlName.Text / ControlName.Value / ControlName.Selected.Value`. The label might need to be visible but you can have the height set to 0

Comment: That's the weird thing. `ControlName.Text` is **always** blank even when I've definitely filled in the text input.